# typescript tuple type comparison differences

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Among the TypeScript Challenge problems, there is a problem called IsNever.
Implement a type IsNever, which takes input type T. If the type of resolves to never, return true, otherwise false.

```
    type A = IsNever<never> expected to be true
    type B = IsNever<undefined>  expected to be false
    type C = IsNever<null>  expected to be false
    type D = IsNever<[]>  expected to be false
    type E = IsNever<number>  expected to be false
```

my solution(wrong answer)

```
type IsNever<T> = T extends never ? true : false;
```

another solution

```
type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true: false;
```

What's the difference between these two solutions?
I wonder what's different when comparing types with tuples.

Answer (score 2):

This is how [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) work.

Think about types as sets of values. Then `T` is a set of all values assignable to `T`, and `never` is an *empty set*. The first syntax basically says (loosely speaking) "does the set `T` contains empty set?". Of course it does. Every set, even an empty one, contains an empty set.